# Interpreter vs compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, interpreter

As we know compiler uses symbol table to store information about all the program data. But how interpreter manages data and what is the actual process interpreter follows?

Comment: Wait...what's the question: How the interpreter manages data, or why it uses less memory than a compiler(which is not always true)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) helps you:-

> During the software development cycle, programmers make frequent
>   changes to source code. When using a compiler, each
>   time a change is made to the source code, they must wait for the
>   compiler to translate the altered source files and link all of the
>   binary code files together before the program can be executed. The
>   larger the program, the longer the wait. By contrast, a programmer
>   using an interpreter does a lot less waiting, as the interpreter
>   usually just needs to translate the code being worked on to an
>   intermediate representation (or not translate it at all), thus
>   requiring much less time before the changes can be tested

Also check out the [comparison](http://www.teach-ict.com/as_as_computing/ocr/H447/F453/3_3_2/translators_compilers/miniweb/pg14.htm) between the two.